# Changing value of variable onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to change variable value on click, so that i can send the value via ajax to load data in ascending or descending format.

Here is Javascript part on top of page.

```
var ascending = '0';
```

Here is HTML Part.

```
<span onclick="knowFormat(true)"><input type="checkbox" id="ascending" name="ascending"><label for="ascending"><i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc"></i>&nbsp;Ascending</label></span>

<span onclick="knowFormat(false)"><input type="checkbox" id="descending" name="ascending"><label for="descending"><i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-desc"></i>&nbsp;Descending</label></span>

<span><input type="button" name="sort" onclick="sorting()"></span>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
input { display:none; }
input:checked ~ label { color:red; }
```

Here is my Javascript just before ajax function and after html, css part:

```
function knowFormat(ascending) {
    if (ascending) { ascending = '0'; } else { ascending = '1'; }
}
```

And in my Ajax, Data is always getting sent '0', even after click.

```
function sorting() {
alert(ascending);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : 'ajax/file.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : 'ascending='+ascending,
        success : function(s) {
            alert(s);
        }
    });
}
```

Even after clicking `sorting`, The `alert` button is always `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the `parameter` due to scope. The same parameter name hides the `global` variable. To change global variable change the name of parameter *or* global variable.

```
function knowFormat(ascending1) {
    if (ascending1) { ascending = '0'; } else { ascending = '1'; }
}
```

Comment: even after clicking , value of ascending is not getting changed.

Comment: Did you debug the code to check what you get in parameter ascending1?